# VirtualBox VM aborted install UbuntuServer 14.04 Assertion Failed

Tags: ubuntu, debian, virtualbox

The title is pretty much explicit, I hope.

Host machine: Debian Wheezy

Guest: Ubuntu Server 14.04

virtualbox installed from host repositories

Here's the log file (lines where the error is):

```
00:15:59.138 !!Assertion Failed!!
00:15:59.138 Expression: pSgBuf->cbSegLeft <= 5 * _1M && (uintptr_t)pSgBuf->pvSegCur >= (uintptr_t)pSgBuf->paSegs[pSgBuf->idxSeg].pvSeg && (uintptr_t)pSgBuf->pvSegCur + pSgBuf->cbSegLeft <= (uintptr_t)pSgBuf->paSegs[pSgBuf->idxSeg].pvSeg + pSgBuf->paSegs[pSgBuf->idxSeg].cbSeg
00:15:59.138 Location  : /build/virtualbox-_9gFzh/virtualbox-4.1.18-dfsg/src/VBox/Runtime/common/misc/sg.cpp(54) void* sgBufGet(PRTSGBUF, size_t*)
00:15:59.138 pSgBuf->idxSeg=0 pSgBuf->cSegs=1 pSgBuf->pvSegCur=00007f0e99fd7000 pSgBuf->cbSegLeft=6291456 pSgBuf->paSegs[0].pvSeg=00007f0e99fd7000 pSgBuf->paSegs[0].cbSeg=6291456
```

I hope someone could help me solve this !
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was given here:

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=70062#p334930

specifically the sentence:

> you are using a third party fork. Switch to the [version we
> support](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)

That does not entirely answer my question, but since the error did not appeared again in the new install and since that might be useful for others...

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue with an older version of VirtualBox (virtualbox-4.1.18) on windows and ubuntu host machines.

The problem was that i was running Ubuntu 14.04.4 server 32bit from the Ubuntu site (vanilla version).

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 server 32bit and it worked!

I then upgraded the install to Ubuntu 14.04.4 and it still works!

It turns out that virtualbox-4.1.18 doesn't like the v4 kernal that comes with vanilla 14.04.4 but it works fine with v3 kernal that comes with Ubuntu 14.04.1 (3.13.0-32-generic). When upgrading the distro to Ubuntu 14.04.4 from 14.04.1, the kernal doesn't get upgraded to v4, but it does get a minor update (3.13.0-86-generic).